# Ruby/Rails : Strip insignificant zeros but only 0 or 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display prices in my rails project. I know I have the `number_to_currency` and the `number_with_precision` methods that could help me.

Even though, I can't find a way to achieve what I want in an elegant manner.

```
display_price(50) # => "50"
display_price(50.5) # => "50.50" this is the one I can't achieve ...
display_price(50.50) # => "50.50"
display_price(50.55) # => "50.55"
display_price(50.551) # => "50.55"
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want the output as a string ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit my question.

Comment: please be there, I will post answer..

Comment: what you want when you have `50.0` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strip off `.00` with a regex:

```
number_with_precision(50, precision: 2).sub(/\.00$/,'') # => "50"
number_with_precision(50.5, precision: 2).sub(/\.00$/,'') # => "50.50"
```

---

Non-rails way:

```
("%0.02f" % 50.5).sub(/\.00$/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do :

```
num = 50.5
val = Float === num ? sprintf("%.2f",num) : sprintf("%d",num)
val # => "50.50"
num = 50.551
val = Float === num ? sprintf("%.2f",num) : sprintf("%d",num)
val # => "50.55"
num = 50
val = Float === num ? sprintf("%.2f",num) : sprintf("%d",num)
val # => "50"
```

You need to look into the method [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) and [`Float#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Float.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) .

Another great suggestion from [*@sawa*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417321/ruby-rails-strip-insignificant-zeros-but-only-0-or-2/22417569#comment34087199_22417569) using [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) method :

```
val = (num.to_i == num ? "%d" : "%.2f") % num
```

Comment: `num = 50.0` => `"50.00"`

Comment: What about `val = (num.to_i == num ? "%d" : "%.2f") % num`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Go ahead. I will not write an independent answer of my own.

Comment: @sawa Don't delete your comment.. Please

Comment: @Matt What is the intention of your comment? Your intention is not clear as much as the OP's intention on that example is not clear.

Comment: @sawa It doesn't obey the intention of the OP's title: "Strip insignificant zeros but only 0 or 2" The 2 0's after the decimal place in "50.00" should be stripped. In any case I don't wish to argue that it is ambiguous - perhaps it is. In any case, that behavior is worth noting, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Matt Actually, I couldn't parse that title, and I am not sure if your interpretation is right. It could be, but it may not be.

Comment: Is there any reason I should accept this answer instead of the other one? In terms of performance? Readability?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger It all up-to you.. :-)